# MySQL could not replicate in case master is down in cluster and then gets up

Tags: mysql, database, replication, mysql-cluster

I have MySQL cluster (NDB) containing 2 servers[NodeA and NodeB].
I have another machine having InnoDB[NodeC] outside cluster.
NodeA is master for NodeC replication slave.
Problem arises when NodeA is down in cluster, and some transaction take place at NodeB of the cluster. When NodeA is again up and running, all data is sync between NodeA and NodeB.
[I set sql_slave_skip_counter=1 into NodeC to remove LOST_EVENT error.]
But the data is not replicated to NodeC.
If after that any transaction takes place data is replicated but the data that is u[dated during downtime of NodeA is not replicated to NodeC.

Am I missing some setting so that Slave starts replicating from the point is left after Master is up again and in sync with other cluster nodes?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-cluster-replication-issues.html

Comment: havnt faced this issue ..the link which i provided you would be helpful