# How to archive tables in MySQL InnoDB

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, archiving

I want to archive my tables that resides in MySQL database using InnoDB as storage engines.
The tables are created using InnoDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can archive table by using `mysqldump`. It can be used to dump a database or a collection of databases for backup or transfer to another SQL server

```
mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=/home/username/.my.cnf database table > table.sql
```

For further reference see [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/479135/mysql-archiving-innodb-tables).

Comment: Does mysqldump compresses the data also.
Also, is there any other way than mysqldump?

Comment: i dont know any other way would do this ..but mysqldump would ..accept the ans if that helps ..:)

Comment: Ok. I will accept it. Let me try first or think of some other scenario/ problem. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Avinash,
Can you please answer/help out in one of my questions?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24939964/mysql-could-not-replicate-in-case-master-is-down-in-cluster-and-then-gets-up

Comment: can you accept this answer is this session is over ??